# Marketplace App: How to access Google Drives of the users on the installed domain?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-apps-marketplace

I am developing a marketplace app in PHP. My app needs to access calendars and drives of all users on the domain, once a domain administrator has installed my app onto their domain, with the appropriate authorizations to the calendar and drive scopes (I am assuming this is possible, without every single user having to grant access).

I am following the example at `https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/tutorial_php` and have been able to access the logged in user's google calendar appointments, using the Zend_Gdata library in the tutorial. Great, so far!

Now I am trying to get my app to talk to user's Drives which is where I am having problems. In the app manifest, my app requests access to the drive scope (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`) in addition to the calendar scope. I am trying to use the current [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) to get access to the logged in domain user's drive. The code looks like this -

```
<?php

require_once 'common.php'; // has all the IDs, keys, secrets etc.
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH_2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH_2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setDeveloperKey($OAUTH_2_DEVELOPER_KEY);
$client->setRedirectUri('http://dev.mydomain.com/g/display.php');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$driveService = new Google_DriveService($client);
$files = $driveService->files->listFiles();
```

The above produces this error-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 
'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key={my_dev_key}: (401) Login Required' 
in /***/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php:66
```

The fact that I can't get a 200 response tells me I am doing the authentication incorrectly, or using the wrong mode of authentication, or something like that. I gather that setDeveloperKey() is required, and the value I am using is the Key for server apps (with IP locking) that I generated in the APIs console. I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.

I am also thinking that the requests need to identify which domain user I want the files for. I have tried passing the parameter `array('xoauth_requestor_id' => $_SESSION['email'])` to the listFiles() function, which cause a different error.

My questions:

1. How do I setup the Google_Client() object correctly so my app can use it to access the user's drives? Do I need to use setDeveloperKey() ? If so, what is the value I should be using?
2. How do I pass Google_DriveService() the currently logged in user's email address so it knows to only return that user's files?

Thanks!

Comment: For authentication, have you looked at the [examples](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fexamples%2Fcalendar)?

Also, please note we (Google) have released a new experience for the Google Apps Marketplace ([see announcement](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2013/11/third-party-apps-now-easier-to-find-and.html)). We also have new [Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/).